# C# POS - The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception

Tags: c#, pos

1. This is the code

   ```
   private PosPrinter GetReceiptPrinter()
   {
       PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
       DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, sPOSPrinterName);

       return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);
   }
   ```
2. I get error upon stepping up on the following line:

   ```
   PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
   ```
3. My Receipt Printer Device: hp a798
4. I already added this code at app.config

   ```
   <runtime>
       <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
   ```
5. As per John, this is the Exception:
   System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
   HResult=-2146233036
   Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception.
   Source=Microsoft.PointOfService
   TypeName=Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer
   StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer.CreateExplorer()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer.LoadExplorer()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer..ctor()

Comment: Is there any chance you could tell us the exception it threw? :)

Comment: Maybe your framework version is too high? See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/058342f8-5238-4b3a-a39e-0427423543e7/new-posexplorer-exception?forum=posfordotnet

Comment: Hello, my framework is: .NET Framework 4

Comment: OK, you've given us some of the stack tract and the fact that it threw an exception, but we still don't know what exception it threw. Please copy the _full_ error message. When the "Exception Unhandled" box comes up, click "Copy details". Paste that information into your question.

Comment: @john, I'll add this inner exception and other details, regarding the full error message, it only shows the title.

Comment: Usually it has a name like `NullReferenceException` or `InvalidOperationException` or something.

Comment: That particular error indicates that the static constructor for `Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer` threw an exception. Static constructors typically contain bullet-proof initialization, since they have to run passively, so your error is probably going to be really obscure, and the root cause may not be obvious, e.g. a .NET framework version mismatch. You might just want to re-install if you can. I am of course just guessing. See if you can find any more text in that there exception message.